# How to create a button or something with title looking like a link, on Windows applications

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, vcl

How to create a button or something with title looking like a link, on Windows applications's windows, dialog boxes, etc? It should receive keyboard focus, and when mouse pointer is over it, its text should be underlined.
I am using C++ Builder. This can be done using TLabel or TStaticText. But the problem is that, it does not receive keyboard focus. I would like it to receive keyboard focus and be tab-stopped.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a [Command Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742403.aspx) control. It provides all features you are looking for, with the exception of underlining the text on hover.

Comment: Thanks. I know about it. I think it is supported on Vista and above.

Comment: Correct. Command Links are available for any supported Windows platform.

Comment: I just need text links that can receive keyboard focus.

Comment: [SysLink control?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `TStaticText` is a windowed control (`TWinControl` descendant) and thus can receive keyboard input.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It must not necessarily be hypertext to URL.
I tried with TStaticText but it does not receive focus. Focused controls usually are surrounded by dashed frame, and when you press enter at that time, it is selected/executed. Please take a look at Skype's Profile window for examples.

Comment: Controls implement focus grabbing and drawing the focus rect themselves. If you are using TStaticText or implementing your own window class for this, you will need to call `SetFocus()` in `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and have `WS_TABSTOP` in each instance, call [`DrawFocusRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `WM_PAINT` if the window does have focus, and handle `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_KILLFOCUS` to redraw your window.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. I will try.

Comment: `DrawFocusRect()` uses XOR and is designed to be lightweight. In `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_KILLFOCUS` just `DrawFocusRect()`, not a full repaint. Likewise, only do `DrawFocusRect()` in `WM_PAINT` if the background gets erased.